# Authorize.net: What Variable Name Should I Use When Posting XML Data? (via ColdFusion CFHTTP)

Tags: coldfusion, authorize.net

I've been using the Authorize.net AIM integration method for many years using a custom built ColdFusion component (CFC).  I want to experiment using the new API and update my CFC to work with it.

Previously all of the transaction data was passed as individual fields which you would post to Authorize.net.
For example: x_login, x_tran_key, etc... would look like this:

```
<cfhttpparam name="x_login" type="formfield" value="xxx" />
<cfhttpparam name="x_tran_key" type="formfield" value="xxx" />
```

With the new API the biggest change I noticed from the developer documentation is that all of the transaction data is encapsulated as a single XML (or JSON) variable and then posted.  However I don't see anywhere in the documentation what the new form field name should be that contains the XML (or JSON) data!

Here's how the flow works:

```
<!--- Create my XML request data:--->
<cfxml variable="xmlRequest">

    <createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">

        <merchantAuthentication>
            <name>xxx</name>
            <transactionKey>xxx</transactionKey>
        </merchantAuthentication>
        <refId>xxx</refId>
        <transactionRequest>
            <transaction request data goes here>
        </transactionRequest>

    </createTransactionRequest>
</cfxml>
```

Then I use CFHTTP to post the data to Authorize.net:

```
<cfhttp url="https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="post">

        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />

        <cfhttpparam name="????" type="formfield" value="#ToString(requestXML)#" />

    </cfhttp>
```

As you can see I don't know what to give the httpparam name for the XML data.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Probably "body" - but let me see if I have some sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you submit XML, you can use:

```
<cfhttp url="https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#ToString(requestXML)#">
</cfhttp>
```

which is basically:

```
<cfhttp url="https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="text/html">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#ToString(requestXML)#">
</cfhttp>
```

---

If you submit JSON, you go:

```
<cfhttp url="https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll" method="post">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json">
    <cfhttpparam type="body" value="#serializeJSON(requestJSON)#">
</cfhttp>
```